# Multiple fixed backgrounds in iOs. Can't get it to work

Tags: html, css, iphone

I'm just learning and doing an assignment on Freecodecamp. My site works well on desktop and when the browser is resized, but it is totally messed up on iOs.
I have searched on here quite a bit, especially sections on background-attachment:fixed & background-size:cover, but all the solutions that I have seen do not work in my case.

```
#parralax1 {background-image: url("https://image.ibb.co/kiRzfF/Office.jpg");
       background-attachment: fixed;
       height: 100%;
       max-height: 100vh;
       background-position: center;
       background-repeat: no-repeat;
       background-size: cover;
       -webkit-background-size: cover;
       position: relative;
       z-index: -1;
```

I have 4 of these one after another. I've been trying various media queries without success. The one on there just now is:

```
 @media screen and (max-device-width: 736px)
 {img{max-width: 100vw; height: auto;}
 #parralax1
 {background-image: url("https://image.ibb.co/kO8MPv/Office960.jpg");
 display: block;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 -webkit-text-size-adjust:none;
 background-repeat: no-repeat important!;  
 background-size: cover important!;
 -webkit-background-size: cover;
 -moz-background-size: cover;
 -o-background-size: cover;
 background-attachment: scroll important!;
 height: 100vh;
 width: 100%;
 z-index: -10;
 overflow-y: scroll;}
 }
```

I just can't get it to work. Can anyone help? Please see full site below:

[my Codepen site](https://codepen.io/born_of_fire/full/BdjPGM/)

[Cut down version](https://codepen.io/born_of_fire/full/ZJxERj/)

Comment: please get the problem down to the least amount of code possible if you want any help..;

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure I know what you mean?

Comment: Your codepen includes the entire site. It would be helpfull if you’d provide us with a codepen which contains just the issue

Comment: Oh, I see. I'll get on it.

Comment: That's me cut it down a bit. The issues are in the id's parralax and their background images. On the iPhone it displays as massively zoomed in, even if I use a smaller image. If I change it from 'background-image' to just 'background', it is no longer zoomed in, but it repeats the image, or rather tiles the image several times. In both cases, you can't scroll down to the second page which is under the div id parralax2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I got this to work by using the 'Modernizr' library. I then took out the 'background-attachment' from each full screen image background and made a separate declaration for non touch devices:

```
       #parralax1 {background: url("https://image.jpg") 
       no-repeat center   center;
       height: 100vh;
       width: 100vw;  
       left: 50%;
       right: 50%;
       margin-left: -50vw;
       margin-right: -50vw;
       position: relative;
       background-size: cover;
       -webkit-background-size: cover;
       z-index: -1;
       }
```

then:

```
       .no-touch #parralax1 {background-attachment: fixed;}
```

then my media query took care of the rest:

```
       @media screen and (max-device-width: 736px)
       {#parralax1 {background-image: url("https://image.jpg")
       !important;
       max-width: 736px;
       max-height: 736px;
       z-index: -1;
       overflow-y: scroll;}
```